# Does Luke 14:26 justify divorce?

Tags: gospel-of-luke, divorce

Does Luke 14:26* justify divorce (or at least separation)?

---

*<sub>[If any man come to me and hateth not his father and mother, and wife and children, and brethren and sisters, yea and his own life besides: he can not be my disciple.]</sub>

Comment: No more so than it justifies suicide - "If any man come to me and hateth not... his own life..."

Comment: This question might work on [hermeneutics.se] where asking about the "correct" interpretation of a specific passage is on topic. "Does X passage mean/imply/justify Y?" as a question format does not work on this site, but it should work on BH.